# Should we use "the lesson" or " a lesson" in the first example and "a passage" or "the passage" in the second one?

Tags: articles, relative-clauses

> Example 1. This video is an excerpt from the lesson in which we are doing a deep reading on a passage adapted from John Bohannon, "“Why You Shouldn’t Trust Internet Comments.”

> Example 2. In this lesson, we analyze a passage adapted from Joshua Foer, "Moonwalking
> with Einstein: The Art and Science of Remembering Everything."

My question is whether we should use "the lesson" or "a lesson" in the first example, and "a passage" or "the passage" in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, it would depend on whether or not you have already referred to a specific lesson. If you have, then '*the* lesson' refers back to that specific one previously mentioned. If you have not mentioned any lesson already and you are presenting this excerpt as an example then 'a lesson' would be appropriate.

The same rule would apply in the second example, although it seems far less likely that you would have referred to this particular passage already. 'A passage' seems correct. Generally speaking, when you provide something as an example, it is precisely that - '*an*' example. There are many passages you could have used, this is just one from among them, so the definite article is not appropriate.

Comment: I hold the same opinion. Thank you for your reply!